# Kettle: collector for rows with different metadata

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-spoon

In Kettle I have two steps with different meta layout that send data to a common User Defined Java Class that acts as data collector (see the following picture for reference).

The output rows sent by the to steps have different metadata. However, the User Defined Java Class always sees the metadata of the first row arrived as `getInputRowMeta()` always return the same information.

Is any method available for getting (refreshed) information about the metadata of the specific row returned by `getRow()`?

[image]

Comment: To use multiple inputs in a step such as this, the metadata of the inputs must be identical. Why is your metadata different? Can you merge the two `Generate rows` steps into one, use a `Select values` step on one output, or merge the two outputs with a `Merge join`?

Comment: So, does this mean that there is no way (even with a custom plugin) to get the specific metadata of each row sent by the previous steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer and a possible solution for this issue is available [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?207342-Collector-for-rows-with-different-metadata).

Comment: `Stream Schema Merge`. Interesting. I'd be inclined to step back and look at the problem you're trying to solve and see if there's another way, but if not, this might work for you.